# Deep Reinforcement Learning with Space Invaders

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I want to better understand Deep Reinforcement Learning so I developed the Space Invaders game from scratch with Pygame. I have a fixed number of enemies (10). Instead of defining the states as a stack of frames (pixels) as in the state of the art, I rather defined them as relative distance between the player and the enemies + relative distance between the player and 5 closest enemy lasers. So the observation space dimension is (10+5)*2 (2 for x and y coordinates). I'm tuning the model for the moment and since I don't see any progression in the behavior (total reward is not really progressing after about 700 episodes), I thought that, beside other hyper parameters, maybe something is wrong with the way I defined the states and I want to have your opinion about it?

Comment: There's lots that can go wrong in Deep RL. Your own game, plus custom state, plus custom agent means there are quite a few places where it could go wrong for you. Have you tried any simpler pre-built components in simpler problems - e.g. something from OpenAI's Gym?

Comment: Yes I did. Since I want to get my hand over all the components of deep RL (environment, agent, actions...) I decided to recreate everything from scratch so, in the long run, I can apply different RL techniques and compare.

Comment: OK, cool, so what have you tried? Have you tried any of your custom work combined with some 3rd-party parts, and how did that work? For instance, have you tried to solve an OpenAI Gym environment using your own agent code, and did it find the optimal policy?

Comment: Actually, after checking out some of the OpenAI's Gym examples, I've seen some tutorials where the environment, the agent and/or the actions are created and where the optimal policy is found. Along with my humble theoretical knowledge, I'm trying to get it done in my own case. Here is my code :  https://github.com/Cyalas/Space_Inv_AI (in DeepQN folder).

Comment: An environment is not really a "component of deep RL". As Neil suggested the only way to test what works and what doesn't is to test your learner in a solvable 3rd-party environment. If it works then maybe something is wrong with your environment. You also test your environment with a 3rd party DeepQ learner. Both these exercises will help you understand what is wrong with your implementation. In general, debugging methods that already work will help you understand better compared to building everything from scratch and try to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: OK I see what you mean. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome!Good luck!